# Take attribute value from where style display is not none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few divs:

```
<div clas="modal-body step step-1" data-step="1" style="display: block;"></div>
<div clas="modal-body step step-2" data-step="2" style="display: none;"></div>
<div clas="modal-body step step-3" data-step="3" style="display: none;"></div>
```

I would like to get the value of attribute `"data-step"` where `style: display` is not `none`.

Is it possible with JavaScript or JQuery?

Comment: Well, since JQuery is JavaScript, there's nothing that one can do that the other can't and, of course, this is possible. The question really is, **what have you tried**? Have you read about how to [query for elements based on their attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)? Have you read about `data-*` attributes and [how to access them via the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)?

Comment: Well, I am ashamed, because first I wrote question, then I think. It can by done by $(".step[display!='none']").attr("data-step")

Comment: `$('.step:visible').attr('data-step');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the :visible selector in jQuery. This will create a node list (like the querySelectorAll that will contain only the item /s that is not hidden. Then you can get the data-step value of that element.

```js
let visibleStep =$(".step:visible");
console.log(visibleStep.attr('data-step')); // gives  1
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wathever">
  <div class="modal-body step step-1" data-step="1" style="display: block;">A</div>
  <div class="modal-body step step-2" data-step="2" style="display: none;">B</div>
  <div class="modal-body step step-3" data-step="3" style="display: none;">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did some sketch on fiddle, try it and let me know if is what you need sir. This is a pure javascript solution.

```js
let nodeList = document.getElementById("wathever").querySelectorAll(".step");
nodeList.forEach(function(div){
   if(div.style.display!="none"){
      //do something
      let dataStep = div.dataset.step;
      console.log(dataStep);
   }
});
```

```html
<div id="wathever">
  <div class="modal-body step step-1" data-step="1" style="display: block;">A</div>
  <div class="modal-body step step-2" data-step="2" style="display: none;">B</div>
  <div class="modal-body step step-3" data-step="3" style="display: none;">C</div>
</div>
```